# React rerendering component on state update but not changing style of component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm probably missing something stupid here. I have a parent component containing a state of selected items. The items are selected in the child component and added to the state list in the parent component. If the item is selected the background color of the child component changes.

It works fine when adding items, but only works for removing items when all items are unselected.

I added a console log in the child component to print out if the child is in the selected list, it is correctly updating the state and rerendering the child component, just not updating the background color.

Function for updating state in parent component

```
//removes account if selected account is already in account list
    //add's if not
    //adds or removes platform from selected platfrorms list for style rendering
        const handleSelectAccounts = (account) => {
        //if first time user has selected account from this platform
        //add platform key and account value to list
        if(!selectedAccounts[account.platform.name]){
            let tempList = {...selectedAccounts}
            tempList[account.platform.name] = [account]
            setSelectedAccounts({...tempList})
            return
        }

        // if account is already in list, remove
        //if there are no accounts for this platform added to list,
        // remove platform, else keep platform in list
        if(selectedAccounts[account.platform.name].length >= 1){
            //loop through accounts in that platform {'platform', [{account1, account2}]}
            for(let i = 0; i < selectedAccounts[account.platform.name].length; i++){
                //if that account is already in the list
                //filter through all of the accounts and return them in a new list
                //leaving out the account being removed
                if(selectedAccounts[account.platform.name][i].id === account.id){
                    if(selectedAccounts[account.platform.name].length === 1){
                        //if platform only has one account that is being removed
                        //delete entire key value pair
                        let tempList = {...selectedAccounts}
                        delete tempList[account.platform.name]
                        setSelectedAccounts({...tempList})
                        return
                    }
                    
                    
                    const filteredAccountList = selectedAccounts[account.platform.name].filter(
                    (acc, index) => {
                        return acc.id !== account.id
                    })

                    setSelectedAccounts(prevObj => {
                        return ({...prevObj, [account.platform.name]:[...filteredAccountList]})
                    })
                    return
                }

            }
            //if account is not already in list, add
            let tempList = {...selectedAccounts}
            tempList[account.platform.name].push(account)
            setSelectedAccounts({...tempList})
            return
        }
}
```

child component:

```
 const SocialAccountSelectItem = ({account, onClick, selectedAccountList}) => {
  const inList = () => {
    if(!selectedAccountList) {return false}

    for(let i = 0; i < selectedAccountList[account.platform.name].length; i++){
      if(selectedAccountList[account.platform.name][i].id === account.id){
        return true
      }
    }
    return false
  }
  
  let style = inList()
  console.log(account.username)
  console.log(style)
  return (
    <button type="button" id={account.username} className={inList() ? "social-account-select-item hover-bg-2" : 'social-account-select-item hover-bg-1'}
    onClick={() => onClick(account)}>
        {account.username}
    </button>
  )
}
```

Comment: For react component to update the CSS, it needs to re-render. A prop or state needs to updated of the component where you want to schedule a re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Check CSS Styles and make sure that the CSS classes "hover-bg-1" and "hover-bg-2" are defined correctly and that they control the background colors as intended.

Debug the child component, it is re-rendering on state update or not.

Try template literals while appending the classes to element, To avoid confusion. Try below code. I have changed `isList` function. Because `selectedAccountList[account.platform.name]` contains an array. We can't always find `account` in `ith` index.

**ChildComponent:**

```
const SocialAccountSelectItem = ({account, onClick, selectedAccountList}) => {
const inList = () => {
  if(!selectedAccountList || !Object.keys(selectedAccountList).length) {return false}

  let { platform, id } = account || {};
  let { name } = platform || {};
  if (!name) {
    return false;
  }

  for (let key in selectedAccountList) {
    let selectedPlatform = selectedAccountList[key];
    if (selectedPlatform && selectedPlatform?.length) {
        let isAccountIdExists = (selectedPlatform || []).filter(acc => acc.id === id);
        if (isAccountIdExists && isAccountIdExists?.length) {
            return true;
        }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
let style = inList()
console.log(account.username)
console.log(style)
return (
    <button
    type="button"
    id={account.username}
    className={`social-account-select-item ${
    inList() ? "hover-bg-2" : "hover-bg-1"}`}
    onClick={() => onClick(account)}
  >
   {account.username}
  </button>
 )
}
```

Try this. If any issue comment below.

Happy coding!!